# Change Structure table

Tags: r

First I want to thank you all for your help. I found a lot of solutions on this website when I was blocked!

Second, I have an issue about performance : Q
I have a table like this:

```
Col1 ; Col2
Entry   X1
Home    X2
Code    X3
Entry   Y1
Home    Y2
Code    Y3
```

and i want this:

```
Col1 ; Col2
X1   ; X2
X1   ; X3
Y1   ; Y2
Y1   ; Y3
```

I manage to do Something, with a for-loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(DateFrame)){    
if(DateFrame[i,1]=="entryId")
{
entryid<-DateFrame[i,2]
}
else {}
DateFrame[i,3]<-entryid}
```

It is works perfectly with 2000 rows. But unfortunalely, i have 30 millions of rows, and after 1 hour of loading, still no result (i=50 000 after 1 hour...)

Can someone help me in this headache?

Thanks you !

EDIT : Here the date frame source

```
df_source = read.table(text = 'V1   V2
entryId 2501100010101820
HomeStore   10,00
Customer    101826
HomeStore   10
Customer    101826
HomeStore   10
Customer    101826
HomeStore   10
Customer    101826
entryId 2501100010101940
HomeStore   10
Customer    101942
HomeStore   10
Customer    101942
HomeStore   10
Customer    101942
HomeStore   10
Customer    101942
entryId 2501100010101990
HomeStore 10
Customer    101999
HomeStore   10
Customer    101999
HomeStore   10
Customer    101999', header = TRUE)
```

Here the dataframe i want

```
df_result = read.table(text = 'V1   V2 Copy
entryId 2501100010101820    2501100010101820
HomeStore   10  2501100010101820
Customer    101826  2501100010101820
HomeStore   10  2501100010101820
Customer    101826  2501100010101820
HomeStore   10  2501100010101820
Customer    101826  2501100010101820
HomeStore   10  2501100010101820
Customer    101826  2501100010101820
entryId 2501100010101940    2501100010101940
HomeStore   10  2501100010101940
Customer    101942  2501100010101940
HomeStore   10  2501100010101940
Customer    101942  2501100010101940
HomeStore   10  2501100010101940
Customer    101942  2501100010101940
HomeStore   10  2501100010101940
Customer    101942  2501100010101940
entryId 2501100010101990    2501100010101990 ', header = TRUE)
```

Comment: If you provide a *working* code-example (on a small toy dataset) you are more likely to get some useful answers. It is not clear (to me at least) how to get from your input to your output. And I do not see how the code you provide does it either. An explanation of your problem in words would also be nice to have.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I gonna add some information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll first create a vector of zeroes, as long as the table has rows.

Then we'll set to 1 the elements of the vector that correspond to a "entryId" row in the table.

If we do a cumulated sum of this vector, we'll have a constant id for each entryId and the subsequent rows such as Homestore etc...

We then map these ids to the actual coordinate of the entryId we're looking for.

And finally we add the column you wanted.

```
entry_flags <- rep(0,nrow(df_source))
entry_flags[which(df_source$V1 == "entryId")] <- 1
entry_row_ids <- which(df_source$V1 == "entryId")
copy_row_ids <- entry_row_ids[cumsum(entry_flags)]
df_source$Copy <- df_source$V2[copy_row_ids]
```

(see edit history for another much less efficient solution)

Comment: Thank you Moody for your help !
Unfortunately it does not work for all lines.
Indeed, i just noticed that sometimes i have 3 lines or 1 line per EntryCode so the repetition=2 doest not work

Comment: If there is no consistent structure it will be hard to do without loops, are these items that mess things up exceptions or are they very frequent ?

Comment: it is very frequent... they are double lines and missing values.. I just add in my first topic the code to create a part of my dataset,

Comment: please try my edited answer and tell me if it's fast enough

Comment: I love u so much <33
your first solution works but take almost 20 hours :D
The second one is instantaneous ! 
I learned a lot with your help, thank you !
I wish you a good day

Comment: haha thanks for the love, I'll edit and explain the answer, then please validate the answer when you can